# Limit django rest framework api according to payment plans

Tags: python, django, api, permissions, django-rest-framework

I have some dynamically added features performed by an admin user, which i will associate with certain endpoints.

What would be a good approach to solve this problem?

The problem is how can i do this association?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/? Until you've got a more concrete question/problem I'm not sure what anyone can advise here except to read through the permissions system and see if it fits what you're after/can be used for whatever it is you're after. (If that doesn't quite fit - then https://github.com/allisson/django-rest-framework-role-filters sounds like it might be feasible)

Comment: I will try to give more details

Comment: i found out a posible solution, now i want to know how good it is.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

1) Stablish some constants strings representing what I know as 'features'. i.e:

- feat1 = 'f1'
- feat2 = 'f2'

2) Used this to create FEATURE_CHOICES into a Feature model. (This one would be created dynamically by admin users. Such users will associate the corresponding choice, and add additional representative metadata, useful for user-agents.

```
FEATURE_CHOICES = ((feat1, 'Awesome feature'), (feat2, 'Just a regular feature'))
```

3) On my views, added the corresponding value as a class variable: api_feature = feat1

4) Created a custom DRF Permission Class that implements a has_feature function which checks if the user's plan has such requested feature.

This is the solution that i've implemented for now. All constants were managed by django-decouple.